Why does prisma freeze during migration?
I just chose prisma as the initializer and suggested one model when I asked prisma to move the developer's name as the initializer to output to the console to combine and all that is needed to install, just as if you know prisma db push
Environment variables loaded from .env
Prisma schema loaded from prisma\schema.prisma
Data source "db": PostgreSQL database "postgres", schema "public" on "localhost:5432".
Please help me, here is the diagram.prisma
generator client {
    provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

data source database {
    provider = "postgresql"
    url = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model De {
    id Int @id @default(auto-increment())
    data string @unique
}

I also tried to enter prisma db push, but the same problem

One problem I can see is that data is a reserved word in Prisma - so please rename the column that you named data, it should solve the problem.
If you want it to be called "data" in the DB, you can use @map("data").
